# Браузер не видит js-функцию

Tags: javascript, html

Подключил скрипт `language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/SCRIPT.js"`.

Написал внутри функцию `function.buttonclick()` и `console.log("Скрипт подключен")`.

Создал кнопку с `onclick="buttonclick()`.

Открыл браузер, нажал кнопку, в консоли не нашёл `console.log`'а, а только:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonclick is not defined

Эта вещь оставалась даже если я скрипт переносил внутрь `<script></script>` с удалением `src()`.

Что я делаю не так?

UPD:

```
function buttonclick() {
    var p = document.getElementById("input");
    var word = ();
    document.getElementById('input').textContent=word;
    var node = p.cloneNode();
    console.log(word);



    var tp = document.createTextNode(word);
}
console.log("Скрипт подключен");
```

Comment: Для начала приведите ваш JS код

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Добавил

Comment: А теперь HTML код)

Comment: возможно, нужно использовать ожидание загрузки страницы или переместить скрипт "под" элемент, вниз страницы.

Comment: Уверены, что у вас `js` включен? Да и аттрибут `language="javascript"` - следует удалить, а  `type="text/javascript"` оставить. Или возможно имя файла с маленьких букв, а подключаете с больших. Что угодно может быть.

Comment: @diproart, тег script находится после /body

Comment: Должен быть перед `</body>`

Comment: @diproart, исправление не изменило ситуацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button id="btn">button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick);

  function btnClick() {
    console.log(btn.innerText);
  }
</script>
```

вариант с onclick:

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="btnClick()">button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

  function btnClick() {
    console.log(btn.innerText);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Это не объясняет, почему не работает `onclick="buttonclick()`

Comment: Добавил вариант обработки события с помощью onclick. Автор не привел код в полном объеме, поэтому чтобы не гадать в чем может быть ошибка, я привел рабочий пример кода. Надеюсь он поможет автору самостоятельно найти ошибку в своем коде.